# AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -22

Tags: android, audio, playback

I am trying to play an mp3 file using the SoundPool class:

---

[SoundPool Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

---

I am running into the aforementioned error however.  The mp3 plays fine on my machine - Win7 64bit.  The error message verbatim:

09-11 20:27:55.256: E/AudioTrack(671): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -22

**Edit**

All the code to perform said function:

```
private SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
private int CLICK_SOUND = 1;



int sp = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.click, 1);
soundsMap.clear();
soundsMap.put(CLICK_SOUND, sp);


AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);          
float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;           
soundPool.play(soundsMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, fSpeed);
```